# Idiomatic use of process substitution

Tags: bash, process-substitution

I have learned Bash process substitution from Bash's man page. Unfortunately, my unskilled usage of the feature is ugly.

```
DEV=<(some commands that produce lines of data) && {
    while read -u ${DEV##*/} FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3; do
        some commands that consume the fields of a single line of data
    done
}
```

Do skilled programmers have other ways to do this?

If an executable sample is desired, try this:

```
DEV=<(echo -ne "Cincinnati Hamilton Ohio\nAtlanta Fulton Georgia\n") && {
    while read -u ${DEV##*/} FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3; do
        echo "$FIELD1 lies in $FIELD2 County, $FIELD3."
    done
}
```

Sample output:

```
Cincinnati lies in Hamilton County, Ohio.
Atlanta lies in Fulton County, Georgia.
```

In my actual application, the "some commands" are more complicated, but the above sample captures the essence of the question.

Process substitution `<()` is required. Alternatives to process substitution would not help.

Comment: Please define the term "idiomatic way". The `read -u ${DEV##*/}` is definitely not an idiomatic way and most probably wrong. Why would you assume that `${DEV##*/}` returns a valid file descriptor to read from? Process substitution may be implemented as a fifo. And the `while read .... done < <(...)` is most probably the most common usage of a process substitution.

Comment: Bash is always ugly.

Comment: @KamilCuk An "idiomatic way" uses the feature as the feature's designer meant it to be used, or uses the feature in a way an experienced, skilled programmer would probably use it, or uses the feature in a way another programmer can easily read and maintain.

Comment: And that makes your question opinion based thus offtopic for this forum. I really rarely see where someone assigns the filename from a process substitution to a variable. Because it's not needed, as it is not needed in your example. Just redirect it to the while loop. (and, if my memory is right, process substitution was buggy and not always worked when the filename get's saved). If you really really really have to have a FD, I would go with `exec {fd}< <(...); read -u $fd`.

Comment: @KamilCuk The file descriptor (FD) is not a requirement. I just did not know how to use the `<()` feature properly. I had read Bash's man page and the above was according to my best understanding of what I had read. Your advice corrects my misunderstanding.

Comment: Then let me point you to a place from where I learned (and still learn) a lot: [greg's wiki about process subsitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)

Comment: @KamilCuk I have tried to edit my question to address your objection. (Whether I have succeeded is for you to decide but, in any case, I appreciate your process-substitution advice.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirect into the loop's stdin with the operator `<`.

```
while read city county state; do
    echo "$city lies in $county County, $state."
done < <(echo -ne "Cincinnati Hamilton Ohio\nAtlanta Fulton Georgia\n")
```

Output:

```
Cincinnati lies in Hamilton County, Ohio.
Atlanta lies in Fulton County, Georgia.
```

Note that in this example, a pipe works just as well.

```
echo -ne "Cincinnati Hamilton Ohio\nAtlanta Fulton Georgia\n" |
    while read city county state
do
    echo "$city lies in $county County, $state."
done
```

Also, uppercase variable names should be reserved for environment variables (like `PATH`) and other special variables (like `RANDOM`). And descriptive variable names are always good.

Answer (score 1):

There are few alternative that will be portable. The 'right' choice depends on the specific case. In particular, it depends on the time to produce the input data, and the size of the input. In particular:

- If it takes lot of time to process the data, you want to get parallel processing between the data generation, and the 'while' loop. This will result in incremental processing, and not having to wait for all the input data processing, before starting output data processing.
- If the input is very large (and does not fit into a shell variable), you might not have a choice but to force an actual pipe. This is also true when the data is binary, Unicode, or similar - where bash variable will not work.

Mapping to the original question - PRODUCE = echo `Cincinnati ...`, and  CONSUME - `echo "$city ..."`

For the trivial case (small input, fast produce/consume), the following will work. Bash will run them SEQUNIALLY: PRODUCE then CONSUME.

```
while read ... ; do
    CONSUME
done <<< "$(PRODUCE)"
```

For the complex case (large input, or slow produce & consume), the following can be use to request PARALLEL execution

```
while read ... ; do
    CONSUME
done < <(PRODUCE)
```

For the PRODUCE code is complex (loops, conditional, etc), or long (multiple lines), consider moving it into a function, instead of in-lining them into the loop command.

```
function produce {
    PRODUCE
}

while read ... ; do
    CONSUME
done < <(produce)
```